# Retrieve database path of any Android application

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a way to retrieve database path of any Android application?

I'm currently writing an application that manipulates database of another application (not mine).
But on several devices/firmwares the database path is different, for example:
`/dbdata/databases/package.name/file.db`
`/data/data/package.name/databases/file.db`

So, how can I retrieve that path at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If there are only these two possibilities just check both with file.exists()

Comment: No, I don't know all the possible variants.

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474538/how-to-access-path-of-database-or-file-of-different-app-in-android

Comment: That seems to be the same solution as "just check both with file.exists()". Databases on Galaxy S, for example, are not under android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory(). That is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

> This should be working

```
File[] files = new File("/data/data/com.dropbox.android.sample/databases/").listFiles(); 
            for (File f:files)
            {

                  if (f.getName().equals("databaseTaskApps"))
                  {

                  }

            }
```