# App installation on the external storage. What will happen with the database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-manifest

My application uses SQL database. What will happen with the location of this database, if I declare `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` in the AndroidManifest? Will it be also stored on the external database? If no, then how should I handle this in my application? (ideally, if user moved the application, I should also move the database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer that other question. if you want to bring have your database on the external storage use the SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase method with the path of the database as the paramters. check the following links. Ive found some examples for you take a look at them.

this is a good one!

[Is it possible to move the internal DB to the SDCard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436434/is-it-possible-to-move-the-internal-db-to-the-sdcard)

heres another example.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

u might want to use the documentation as a reference.. Good luck!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase(java.lang.String, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, int, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)

Comment: my question is a little bit different now - how can I catch the event, when user moved the application to SD card (so, I'll move database accordingly).

Comment: I don't know if that is possible. I dont think android actually broadcast the event when your application gets shifted to external storage. However, maybe one way is to check using

ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()
to get the file directory your application resides in every single startup of your application. I am not really sure if its a good way but it'll work is'nt it.. try to readup more on external storage. maybe u'll find something lurking in the docs xD

Answer (score 2):

The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are saved on the internal device memory.

from: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

the database will still remain on the internal storage of your phone. you don't have to handle this android will handle it for you

Comment: Thanks, @Rejinderi. What if I want to move my database to external storage? How can I understand where application is?